# finding example for modular law if the condition C⊆B is necessary

Tags: modules

B,C and D are submodule of module A.

$B\cap (C+D)=C+(B\cap D)$  ( modular law)

i am trying to find example the condition $C \subseteq B$ is necessary for modular law.

For example if i take  $B=\{1,2\}$ and $C=\{1,3\}$ and $D=\{3,4\}$

and then $(\{1,2\}\cap(\{1,3\}+\{3,4\})) \neq (\{1,3\}+(\{1,2\}\cap\{3,4\})$

Is it true ?  Can i choose this elements for $B$, $C$ and $D$ like that ?
any help would be appreciated .
+ is not instead of U.

Comment: Do you mean sets, not modules? Do you mean the union, denoted "$\cup$" instead of "+" (meaning ambiguous)?

Comment: Your "For example..." is confusing since you begin your question with "..of **module** $\;A\;$." , so it'd seem you need here *modules*, not simply sets which, in general, we don't know how to sum with each others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum and intersection of submodules](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580873/sum-and-intersection-of-submodules)

Answer (score 1):

Take $\;A:=2\Bbb Z\le \Bbb Z\;,\;\;B=6\Bbb Z\,,\,\,C=4\Bbb Z\,,\,D=10\Bbb Z$ , then:

$$\begin{cases}B\cap(C+D)=B\cap A=B\\{}\\C+(B\cap D)=C+30\Bbb Z=A\end{cases}\;\;\text{and}\;\;A\neq B$$